# Find plane normal and origin from homogeneous matrix

Tags: matrices

Given a $3\times 4$ matrix how do I find the plane equation ?

My matrix is as follows:
$$
\left[
\matrix
{
a&b&c&d \\
e&f&g&h \\
i&j&k&l
}
\right]
$$

Where $X_1=(a,b,c,d) $; $X_2=(e,f,g,h)$ and $X_3=(i,j,k,l)$ are $3$ distinct points expressed in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics). Those $3$ points in space, define a plane such as $Ax + By + Cz  + D = 0$,  ($A, B, C, D$ constants not all zero). How do I find those $A,B,C,D$ values ?

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb R^4$? The points are telling that!

Comment: No it's $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: You're working in projective space, $\mathbb{RP}^3$.